# Double redirection with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have this .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# put trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# to make pretty urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?get=$1/ [QSA,L]
```

The problem is when I look at firebug's console, I see that all resources (.js, .css) are getting called twice.

What is wrong with this htaccess file?

Thanks a lot!
(and sorry about my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your first rule to:

```
# put trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD}  !=POST
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

Make sure to test in a new browser to avoid caching issues.

Comment: looks like is a .less thing. Looking at apache's log theres only one petition. But looking at firebug's console, still twice.

Comment: Can you try this in a new browser as you were using 301 earlier?